# Index out of bounds in textbook example

Tags: python, numpy, nlp

I am trying to follow a textbook example of training a perception, but I keep running into an `index out of bounds error`. I am following the textbook 'Natural Language Processing In Action by Hobson Lane, Cole Howard, & Hannes Max Hapke'.

This is the data:

```
sample_data = [[0, 0], # False, False
[0, 1], # False, True
[1, 0], # True, False
[1, 1]] # True, True

# for toy example you can list out the expected outputs although in real life this is never the case
expected_results = [0, # (False OR False) gives False
1, # (False OR True ) gives True
1, # (True OR False) gives True
1] # (True OR True ) gives True
activation_threshold = 0.5

from random import random
import numpy as np

weights=np.random.random(2)/1000 # 2 small random floats divided by 1000 0<w<0.001
print(f'random weights:  {weights}')
bias_weight=np.random.random()/1000 #return 1 small random float divided by 1000
print(f'bias:{bias_weight}')
# f-strings allow you to insert values into string w/o type conversion
```

This is the code for running the perceptron, but I keep running into an error on the line below the last for-loop `new_weights.append(weights[i]+((expected_results[idx]-perceptron_output)*x))`

```
for iteration_num in range(5):
    correct_answers=0
    for idx, sample in enumerate(sample_data):
        input_vector= np.array(sample)
        weights=np.array(weights)
        activation_level=np.dot(input_vector, weights)+(bias_weight)
        if activation_level>activation_threshold:
            perceptron_output=1
        else:
            perceptron_output==0
        if perceptron_output==expected_results[idx]:
            correct_answers+=1
        new_weights=[]
        for i, x in enumerate(sample):
            new_weights.append(weights[i]+((expected_results[idx]-perceptron_output)*x))
            bias_weight=bias_weight+((expected_results[idx]-perceptron_output)*1)
            weights=np.array(new_weights)
    print(f'{correct_answers} correct answers out of 5, for iteration {iteration_num}')
```

This is what the error looks like.

[image: error]

I wrote the code exactly how it is shown in the textbook, but I keep getting this error. When I tried to run the line separately, it was working fine.

[image: Working fine]

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
        for i, x in enumerate(sample):
            new_weights.append(weights[i]+((expected_results[idx]-perceptron_output)*x))
            bias_weight=bias_weight+((expected_results[idx]-perceptron_output)*1)
            weights=np.array(new_weights)
```

You are overwriting the very important `weights` array every time through the loop.  In the first loop, `new_weights` will only have one element, so the second time through the loop, `weights` only has one element.

You need to out-indent that last line so it is AFTER the loop, not PART of the loop.

By the way, earlier in that function, you do not need `weights = np.array(weights)`.  It is already an array.